# Refreshing and changing the URL automatically?

Tags: automation, html, page-refresh

What I want to do is;

Refreshing a website and at the same time changing a part of the URL which includes numbers. Assume that you are viewing pictures on a website one by one;

images/31
images/32
images/33

and there is no slideshow on the website so you have to change the image number in the URL by hand. What I want to do here is automizing this procedure in a way. That number will increase by one in every 5 sec. Is that possible?

Comment: Don't you mean a redirect? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Examples

Comment: Actually, I won't design or change a website. I want to refresh a webpage which its URL includes subsequently increasing numbers. Unfortunately, the website does not have a slide show for the pictures. I should change the url each time. Assume that the URL finishes with images/31 and the next page is image/32. Instead of changing the numbers one by one, I want to automatize this if there is a tool achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

USE HTML5

just think of a way how you will automate passing the variable to this function

```
 setInterval(function(){
  window.history.replaceState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/another-new-url)
    }, 5000);
```

check this: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page

Comment: Actually, I won't design or change a website. I want to refresh a webpage which its URL includes subsequently increasing numbers. Unfortunately, the website does not have a slide show for the pictures. I should change the url each time. Assume that the URL finishes with images/31 and the next page is image/32. Instead of changing the numbers one by one, I want to automatize this if there is a tool achieving this.